# I am making app in kotlin but it keeps crashing, yet before launching it doesnt show errors

Tags: java, android, kotlin, crash

Its a simple app that is supposed to choose random line from a text file.
I tried installing android 8.0 because last error I ever got was that I require level 26 or higher. I am new to android studio and I don't understand the crash log

```
package com.example.exampleapp

import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import kotlin.random.Random
import java.io.File
import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Paths
import java.util.stream.Stream

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.rollButton)
        val resultsTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)



        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
                val i = Random.nextInt(1, 9)
                val line = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("chal.txt")).get(i)
                resultsTextView.text = line
        }
    }

}
```

After launching the app it immediately crashes. Here's the log:

```
2022-12-05 13:01:22.217 8637-8637/com.example.exampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.exampleapp, PID: 8637
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:558)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) 
     Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: chal.txt
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
        at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3202)
        at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3242)
        at com.example.exampleapp.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda$0(MainActivity.kt:28)
        at com.example.exampleapp.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$qUvL8i7QyFzeRpgsUagxdHIDpUc(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.exampleapp.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1131)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
        at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

I don' really understand it

Comment: `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: chal.txt` here is a useful piece of that crash log.

Comment: You can't get file handles like that on Android. You need to put your file in `assets` or `res/raw` so it will be packaged with the compiled app, and get the handle using the appropriate function. Read the documentation about file resources.

Answer (score 0):

Hey there :D There are two important parts of the crash log:

`MainActivity.kt:28`
and
`java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: chal.txt`

The second error is stating that "chal.txt" in fact does not exist, which intern crashes the app when it tries to read it. And to back this up I believe `val line...` (where its trying to read "chal.txt") is line 28.

Let me know if this helps :)

EDIT:

This is in answer to "I don't understand the crash log". I don't actually know how to fix your problem but at least help you understand the problem :)

Comment: isnt it should crash on pressing the button?

Comment: @nope sorry I don't understand your question.